# c execute external program multiple times

Tags: c, pipe, system

i'm trying to call an external program from my code with some arguments. As i'm trying to see how different parameters change it's output i have to run it multiple times (about 1000 times). Every time the external program runs i'm just interested in one line of its output although it is printing a lot of (for my purpose) useless stuff. The line i'm interested in is right above the special identifier("some_signal") in the output. So i thought i'll wait till this line appears and read the line above.

I tried the following:

```
 pid_t pid = 0;
  int pipefd[2];
  FILE* output;
  char line[256];               // pipe read buffer
  char prev_line[256];          // prev. line pipe buffer
  char signal[] = "some_signal\n";
  int status = 0;
  double obj_Val;

  pipe (pipefd); //create pipe
  pid = fork (); //span child process
  if (pid == 0)
    {
      // redirect child's output to pipe
      close (pipefd[0]);
      dup2 (pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
      dup2 (pipefd[1], STDERR_FILENO);
      execl ("/some/path",
         "some/path",
         "some_argument", (char*) NULL);
    }
  else if (pid < (pid_t) 0)
    {
      printf("fork failed \n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  else
    {
      // get child output to pipe
      close (pipefd[1]);
      output = fdopen (pipefd[0], "r");


      while (fgets (line, sizeof(line), output), signal != NULL)
        {
          if(strcmp(line, signal) == 0)
           {
             obj_Val = atof (prev_line);
             kill (pid, SIGTERM);
             waitpid (pid, &status, WNOHANG);
             kill (pid, SIGKILL);
             waitpid (pid, &status, 0);
             break;
           }//end if
          strcpy (prev_line, line);
        }//end while
     }
```

This works fine for like 100 runs or so and then one out of two errors occurs. The first one is a segmentation fault. The second one is the calling program printing out all the output of the called program (without the line containing the wanted signal) and goes into an infinite loop (my guess is, since the signal is missing the while loop won't terminate).
Maybe someone can provide a hint or a link where to look and what to look for, or preferably tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` condition is broken: `signal != NULL` is always true, as `signal` is an array; and because of the comma `,` operator the entire condition is always true.

And because of the following, you're not checking the return value of `fgets`, which means that nothing was read and the buffer is uninitialized.

Also `prev_line` is not initialized before you do `atof` on it for the first time.

---

In any case, compile with `-Wall -Werror` and fix the remaining errors.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So that part works. But now it seems after a while the created process needs more and more time to shut down.  What might be the reason?

Comment: Please ask a new question for that